# HTML Object Embed sound volume

Tags: html, object, audio, embed, volume

I don't know why, but the VOLUME attr is not working. It can be 0 or 100 I can't hear any difference.

```
<object>
    <param name="autostart" value="true">
    <param name="src" value="scream14.wav">
    <param name="autoplay" value="true">
    <param name="controller" value="true">
    <embed src="scream14.wav" volume="0" hidden="true" controller="true" autoplay="true" autostart="true" type="audio/wav" loop="false"/>
</object>
```

Comment: What is your player?  The parameters can vary depending on what is playing the audio.  There is no standard when it comes to embedding plugins.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the code and it was running correctly

Comment: this is not an answer to the question, this is a comment